# How to refer external JS files with Jquery in cshtml Razor page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to develop an application in ASP.Net MVC5. I have written some JQuery functions in my Razor page. I want to take those JQuery functions to an external JS file and include it to the .cshtml page.
this is how I referred the Js file in .cshtml file

```
<script src="~/Js/Driver.js"></script>
```

If I write `alert("External JS file loaded successfully");` in my `Driver.js` file, the message box is popped up successfully. But if I write this function

```
$("#btnCreate").click(function () {
alert("Create button clicked");});
```

in that file, it shows below error in console.

[image]

how to fix this?

Comment: You need to include `jquery-{version}.js` in your view (or layout)

Comment: I have included it in my _layout.cshtml file. internal JQuery functions are working successfully. My problem occurs when I migrate JQuery functions to an external js file.

Comment: Have you referenced Jquery? $ is a Jquery syntax

Comment: @RachitGupta I have referred the JQuery in the layout page. But not in my view page (cshtml) or external js file.